# Any way to use the `@Procedure` annotation without an entity?

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, spring-data-jpa, spring-repositories

So I'd like a "Void-Repository" through which to gain access to stored procedures that are not necessarily operation on entities.

```java
@Repository
public interface StoredProceduresRepository extends CrudRepository<Void, Long> {

    @Procedure("my_answer_giver")
    String getMyAnswer(@Param("input") String input);
}
```

But that does, of course, not work because the `CrudRepository` expects `Void` to be an entity.

Is there a way to use the `@Procedure` annotation without having to create dummy entities or am I stuck with an implemented class that makes use of the `EntityManager` to query via prepared statements?

Because let's be honest, that's fugly:

```java
@Repository
public class StoredProceduresRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    public String getMyAnswer(String input) {
        Query myAnswerGiver = em
            .createStoredProcedureQuery("my_answer_giver")
            .registerStoredProcedureParameter("input", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
            .setParameter("input", input);
        Object result = ((Object[]) myAnswerGiver.getSingleResult())[0];
        return (String) result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is ok for you you can use any Entity you have, in place of this `Void`. The Entity provided there should not matter.

```
public interface StoredProceduresRepository extends JpaRepository<SomeUnrelatedEntity, Long> {

        @Procedure("my_answer_giver")
        String getMyAnswer(@Param("input") String input);

}
```

[I have been using it like this with database views.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53508460/534877)

Comment: We have been discussing it, but in the end, we feel that using an unrelated entity is a bit of a design inconsistency that we would rather not live with. Granted, we may be a bit pedantic, in that regard. :P

Comment: If you have some kind of `BaseEntity` in your system you could try tu use that. Or maybe Spring's `AbstractPersistable`: https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-data-jpa/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/domain/AbstractPersistable.html

Comment: `AbstractPersistable` doesn't work, but using our base entity seems to. Think I may be able to sell that to the team. Thank you.

Comment: Did you create a dummy entity?