# How can I reference a view in the entity? (Spring Boot)

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, view

I have a question. Of course, I have previously looked on the Internet and searched for the solution. Unfortunately, I have not found a solution.

I have a Spring Boot application that processes the information from customers. But this application should not point to a table as usual but to a view that requests information from two tables. How do I have to modify my entity to refenence to the view?

My View

```
CREATE VIEW customers_view
SELECT
    customer_id, firstname, lastname,
    (SELECT ordernumber FROM orders
     WHERE orders.customer_id = custoumer.id
     ORDER BY customer_id DESC)
FROM customers
```

My Entity

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CustomerInformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "customer_id")
    private Long customer_id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String firstname;
    
    @Column(name = "ordernumber")
    private String firstname; 
}
```

Comment: Skip the subquery, do a LEFT JOIN instead. (As it is now you'll get an error if a customer has more than one order.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Actually it's about another entity but I didn't want to publish it. So I just created a case study. It is really only a 1 to 1 relationship to be established.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some examples for referencing views using spring boot:
[JPA/SpringBoot Repository for database view (not table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53508168/jpa-springboot-repository-for-database-view-not-table)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is something like this

```java
@Getter
@Entity
@Immutable
@Table(name = CustomerInformation.VIEW_NAME)
@Subselect(CustomerInformation.QUERY)
public class CustomerInformation implements Serializable {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5285590166874166801L;

    public static final String VIEW_NAME = "V_CUSTOMER_INFORMATION";
    public static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM " + VIEW_NAME;

    @Id
    @Column(insertable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

}
```